# Timeline database schema?

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm having trouble finding a good database structure/schema for a timeline.

I have a site where a user can create many types of objects, these objects have many different properties and so are saved in many different tables.

My timeline does display all the different objects ordered by date.

My idea was to insert a record in my timeline table when a new object is created:

```
insert into timeline (date, objectType, objectId) values (...)
```

To display my timeline i do:

```
select * from timeline order by date desc limit 100
```

No problem here. Next i need to get the object data that will be displayed on my timeline, simply:

```
select * from objectType where id = objectId
```

for every single entry in my timeline. And this will becomes the problem, these are way to many queries.

Of course i can fine tune it with:

```
select * from objectType where id in (objectId, objectId)
```

But still when there are many objectTypes in my timeline it still are a lot of queries.

Anyone got a bright idea on a better approach?

Comment: what's wrong with `IN`? You can do it in one query. but depending on your application structure, you might have to do deferred execution or rendering.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath with IN you will have 1 query for every objectType, if there are for example 10 objectTypes with each their own table you will have 10 queries for every objectType + the timeline one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say which flavour of SQL you're using, so it's hard to say what kind of syntax to answer with.  Here is some pseudo-code to give you an idea:

Create a temporary table (or view) that connects the displayable details of different types using `UNION` and then select the TOP/LIMIT from that.

You can join the timeline to your various object types, projecting each object type's properties into a consistent displayable format based on converting the native columns in each object type:

```
CREATE VIEW displayable_events
AS
select 
  e.date, e.objectType, e.objectID, 
  o.ColumnOfInterest1 + '-' + o.ColumnOfInterest2 as Description
                      -- Or whatever you want to show
from timeline e 
  inner join objectTypeA o
    on e.objectID = o.objectID
where e.objectType = 'TypeA' -- or whatever you're using to distinguish them.
--
UNION ALL
--
select 
  e.date, e.objectType, e.objectID, 
  o.ColumnOfInterest1 + 'anything else you like' as Description
from timeline e 
  inner join objectTypeB o
    on e.objectID = o.objectID
where e.objectType = 'TypeB' 
--
UNION ALL
--
... and so forth for all of your object types...
```

Then you can select from this view (or temporary table) like so:

```
SELECT * from displayable_events
WHERE -- whatever you use to distinguish whose timeline you want ---
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 100
```

This saves you doing all of the queries individually for each timeline entry because it uses a set-based approach.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on the subject, i'm going to dive a bit into views cause i never really worked with them.